# Using ES6 in WebStorm provide errors

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to use ES6 in WebStorm (node.js app) and I got error while for example I use `import etc`.

I go to preferences ->language and change to ECMASCRIPT6 and in addition right click and choose javascriptlibrary and choose ecma script 6, so why I get errors ?

I use WebStorm 2016.2

This is the error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {expect} from 'chai';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

**UPDATE**

**This is the code i've used**

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import path from "path";
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {expect} from 'chai';
```

Comment: Friend, your question is not clear. I think you are missing some words in your first line sentence, which makes us hard to understand the problem.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for the edit.

Comment: This is an error, you can't use `import` inside an IIFE, you shoud use `require` (commonJS style)

Comment: @topheman - I dont use IIFE

Comment: import statements must be at the top of the file. also why are you importing the same twice?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon - of course the import is my first statment of the file,where i do it twice?

Comment: after your imports you hace an IIFE with an import statement in ti according to your code sample

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon - this is the showen error this is not my code...

Comment: As the comments above stated, the `import` is not in the right place, this is because you have a syntax error. But to go deeper, the reason you have an `import` statement here might be because this part is not transpiled (or something like that) ?